# Find and Replace for Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, replace

I'm trying to create a Find/Replace thing for my text area. I got the find done but I can't get the replace code together.

My search code is:

```
function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
}

function selectString(input, string) {
    var match = new RegExp(string, "i").exec(input.value);
    if (match) {
        setSelectionRange(input, match.index, match.index + match[0].length);
    }
}
```

How would I make a replace function if possible?

Comment: this link may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365902/search-for-all-instances-of-a-string-inside-a-string

Comment: Don't you see it? Its, How would I make a replace function if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function in Javascript.  It accepts a regular expression for the search string.

```
string = string.replace(input.value, "replace value here")
```

Comment: I want a real one thought. I need it so I can click Next and it will show the next found item.

Answer (score 0):

For the find dialog:

I had the same question and nobody could answer it! I made a JDialog with a JLabel, JTextField and two JButtons (next and previous). I added action listeners so that when a key was released on the JTextField it would select the first occurrence of the word using .indexOf(myTextField.getText());. I then had the next and previous buttons find the word with action listeners. If you still want the code then just comment, I'll find it on my computer.