# Search a string to find all the letters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I search for the word "i" in the text, but it only shows the first "i" and does not show the rest of "i"
I want you to show me the whole text though
Help me please

```js
const searchItem = () => {
  const source = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit."
  const searchDate = "i";
  for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    let res = source.search(searchDate);
    if (res > 0) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    } else if (res < 0) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "No results found";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="searchItem()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4009768/1461850

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Your call `source.search(searchDate)` is always the same, it does not depend in any way on the value of `i`. The `for` loop has no effect on the `search` call, it is just repeated a lot of times, and every time it runs in exactly the same manner.

Comment: What you want to return? currently you return the number of "i" occurrences
it is 6 (not 7) because it is 0 indexed

Comment: @iota In the above sentence, there is more than one i. I want to show me the index of all available i, for example, the result "6, 19" means the places where i exists, show their index

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count string occurrence in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string)

Comment: If you just want to count the occurences instead of writing this much code u can simply use split method to count the letter occurrences

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search for all instances of a string inside a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365902/search-for-all-instances-of-a-string-inside-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String#indexOf` with the fromIndex argument to continuously search for the string.

```js
const searchItem = () => {
  const source = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit."
  const searchDate = "i";
  const indexes = [];
  let i, prev = 0;
  while((i = source.indexOf(searchDate, prev)) !== -1){
    indexes.push(i);
    prev = i + searchDate.length;
  }
  if (indexes.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = indexes;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "No results found";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="searchItem()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) returns the index of the first match. It does not search the whole string.

---

Since the for loop in the code isn't used, You're probably trying use that loop to compare each char in the string;

```js
const searchItem = () => {
    const source = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit."
    const searchDate = "i";
    let res = 0;

    // For each character in source
    for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        
        // If current char matches searchDate
        if (source[i] === searchDate) {
        
            // Bumb result counter
            res++;
        }
    }

    // After looping through all the chars, show result based on res
    if (res > 0) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    } else if (res < 0) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "No results found";
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="searchItem()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const searchItem = () => {
  const str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit."
  const res = str.split("i").length - 1;
  if (res > 0) {
    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = res;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = "Invalid";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="searchItem()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

If your aim is to only find the occurrences of letters in word then that can be done by simple **split** method.

```js
const str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.";
const result = str.split("i").length - 1;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: edited my post  u can check it

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like you're trying to count the occurrences within a string, this should do:

```js
var findOccurrences = () => {
   var searchQuery = document.getElementById('searchQuery').value;
   var source = document.getElementById('source').value;

   var regExp = new RegExp(searchQuery, 'g');
    
   var match = source.match(regExp);
   var occurrences = 0;
   
   if(match) {
    occurrences = match.length;
   }

   document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = occurrences > 0 ? occurrences : "No results found";
 }
```

```html
<input id="source" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit."/>
<input id="searchQuery" />
<button onclick="findOccurrences()">Try it</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

another way.
get the length of the string. replace all occurrences and get the length again, the difference is your result.

```js
const searchItem = () => {
      const source = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit."
      const searchDate = "i";
      const initialLen = source.length;
      const replacedLen = source.split(searchDate).join("").length;
      const diff = initialLen - replacedLen;
      if(diff > 0){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = diff
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "No results found";
      }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="searchItem()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    const searchItem = () => {
        const source = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit."
        const searchDate = "i";
        const demo = document.getElementById("demo");
        for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
            if (source[i] === searchDate)
                demo.innerHTML += i + ' ';
        if (demo.innerHTML === '')
            demo.innerHTML = "No results found";
    }
</script>
```